# The glGetUniformLocation issue with a structure

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

there.

I have some code that working in Java but in C++ it faults.

```
int globalAmbLoc = glGetUniformLocation(this->rendering_program_geometry, "globalAmbient");

if (globalAmbLoc == -1) throw exception("No globalAmbLoc in the vertex shader");

glProgramUniform4fv(this->rendering_program_geometry, globalAmbLoc, 1, &GLOBAL_AMBIENT[0]);

int ambLoc = glGetUniformLocation(this->rendering_program_geometry, "light.ambient");

if (ambLoc == -1) throw exception("light.ambient");
```

Where light is:

```
struct PositionalLight
{
vec4 ambient;
vec4 diffuse;
vec4 specular;
vec3 position;
};

uniform PositionalLight light;
```

Why does ambLoc get "-1" when trying to get any field from the structure?

Answer (score 0):

It's bacause I not using light's fields in the shader. Only variables that "in use" can be linked.